# How to combine two select statements into one select statement in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, select

```
select1         select2     
a1  b1  c1      a2  b2  c2 (column name)
34  64  65      45  67  54
34  43  65      74  75  54
63  54  45      546 76  46


    combined                    
    a1  b1  c1  a2  b2  c2
    34  64  65  45  67  54
    34  43  65  74  75  54
    635 54  45  54  76  46
```

query:

```
SELECT t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t2.a2, t2.b2, t2.c2                     
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                       
WHERE t1.time between '2018-03-05' and '2018-03-06' 
AND t2.time between  '2018-03-05' and '2018-03-06';
```

Hi, I wonder how I combine two SELECT statements into one SELECT statement just like the above picture. I want them to combine with columns, just like the picture.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Does Table1 and Table2 have anything in common? if not, Does select1 and select2 have an order by clause?

Comment: Nope, no common or order by clause.

Comment: in that case generate row numbers from both the tables and  join on that  row number column.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would use an `inner join` for things like that. But `inner join` needs some common columns between the two objects it joins, and you don't have that.
Since your queries also does not contain an `ORDER BY` clause, there is no reliable way to join them so that each row in `table1` will always be joined to the same row in `table2`.
However, since both tables have a `time` column, you can use that:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  a1, 
            b1, 
            c1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [time]) AS rn
    FROM Table1
    WHERE time between '2018-03-05' and '2018-03-06'
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  a2, 
            b2, 
            c2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [time]) AS rn
    FROM Table2
    WHERE time between '2018-03-05' and '2018-03-06'
)

SELECT t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t2.a2, t2.b2, t2.c2                     
FROM cte1 as t1
INNER JOIN cte2 as t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: From my studio, the last SELECT section, SELECT t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t2.a2, t2.b2, t2.c2  does not work. The red lines appear under the names. Is it possible to remove the rn columns from the display?

Comment: Oops, I've accidentally removed the aliases when coping your original query. Edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Again, glad to help :-)

Comment: One more question Mr Peled, Why do we use ';'  at start? It's fine without that ';' isn't it?

Comment: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#guidelines-for-creating-and-using-common-table-expressions) states :"When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.". So a lot of developers just use a semicolon before the `with` keyword as a default, just so we will not forget to separate the cte from the statement before it. It's unnecessary in this case, but a good habit to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select a.a1,a.b2,c.a1,b.a2,b.b2 ,b.c2 from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on table1 any row <> table 2 any row
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I just uploaded the picture and I wonder where I need to put WHERE statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not have any column to join then you can generate row number and join on that. Not very sure about the business but below will work here. Change join to required if number of rows are different in both the tables.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yourOrderbyColumn) rnk
    from table1
)
,CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yourOrderbyColumn) rnk
    from table2
)
SELECT * FROM CTE a 
INNER JOIN CTE1 b ON a.rnk = b.rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about SQL basics and it looks your first attempt can work, by the way here is another common style you can write it:

```
SELECT  t1.a1,
        t1.b1,
        t1.c1,
        t2.a2,
        t2.b2,
        t2.c2                     
FROM table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.time = t1.time
WHERE t1.time between '2018-03-05' and '2018-03-06' ;
```